# Is it possible to do a Windows Installer minor upgrade when a file changes

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade

Do you have to trigger a Major upgrade with a Windows Installer if one of the files has changed since the previous install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can get away with a minor upgrade. See the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370037(VS.85).aspx) for more information.

> A minor upgrade can be used to add
>   new features and components but cannot
>   reorganize the feature-component tree.
>   Minor upgrades provide product
>   differentiation without actually
>   defining a different product. A
>   typical minor upgrade includes all
>   fixes in previous small updates
>   combined into a patch. A minor upgrade
>   is also commonly referred to as a
>   service pack (SP) update.

Basically you can update files without any problems.